# Sorting Pending Changes in Visual Studio Team Explorer 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, team-explorer, team-explorer-everywhere

Does anyone know if there's a way to add more columns to the list of pending changes in team explorer for visual studio 2013? The point is that I'd like to, for example, sort the list of pending changes by last modified. I can't seem to find a way to do it or any information about it online.

Thanks!

Comment: It doesn't look like it, no. There is a filter though, under View Options, if you want to see a subset.